# Android Presentation and Layout Design

Tags: android, user-interface, presentation

I've been working on testing some of the Presentation API for a project and am running into an issue where the layout that is being used is not the expected layout.

We have a few different types of external displays that we'll be using, and I'd like the app to choose the correct layout file.  The phone really wants to present the standard layout file - and it looks terrible in presentation mode on this TV vs how it looks on a phone.

My test code:

Main Activity:

```
//Display manager for external display
    displayManager =  (DisplayManager)getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    if (displayManager!= null){
        presentationDisplays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
        Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();
        if (presentationDisplays.length > 0){
            SecondaryDisplay secondaryDisplay = new SecondaryDisplay(MainActivity.this, presentationDisplays[0]);
            secondaryDisplay.show();
        }
    }
```

*SecondaryDisplay.java*

```
public class SecondaryDisplay  extends Presentation {
/**
 * Creates a new presentation that is attached to the specified display
 * using the default theme.
 *
 * @param outerContext The context of the application that is showing the presentation.
 *                     The presentation will create its own context (see {@link #getContext()}) based
 *                     on this context and information about the associated display.
 * @param display      The display to which the presentation should be attached.
 */
public SecondaryDisplay(Context outerContext, Display display) {
    super(outerContext, display);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary_display);
}
```

I have created this secondary_display.xml and it looks like garbage on the TV no matter what I seem to do

Images are stretched awkwardly and the fonts are stretched.  Everything is too tall.

I created an alternate layout folder called layout-port-television (the TV is in portrait mode)

and made alternate versions of the layouts in this folder, hoping they'd be used, but the regular layout versions were still used.

So I deleted the regular layout versions and left only the TV versions and the app crashed with this:

> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0060
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:285)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2514)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1357)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:530)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:541)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:858)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.edtest.presentationtest.SecondaryDisplay.onCreate(PosSecondaryDisplay.java:56)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:708)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:422)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:285)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.edtest.presentationtest.MainActivity$1.onDisplayAdded(MainActivity.java:145)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:1575)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8462)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
> 04-11 09:02:41.659 28878 28878 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

The layout is there.  If I move it out of that television folder to the regular layout folder it works fine

here's the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondaryDisplay">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="This Text Should Be Centered"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/beer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The "beer" image is a square png file - 128x128 - 72ppi
The "logo" image is 1000 x 159 png - 72ppi

The beer and logo images both appear stretched vertically
and the text appears stretched vertically

I'd like to figure out how to get them to appear normally and not stretched

Do I need to use alternate folders for this TV output with the presentation API?
If so any idea how to best figure out what might be used so I can build the right versions?

Thanks!

***EDIT***

Based on recommendations from @CommonsWare I added some debug output to my Display check and got some odd results

```
if (displayManager!= null){
            presentationDisplays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
            Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();
            Point point = new Point();
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            for (int i=0; i<displays.length; i++) {
                addToLog("DISPLAY: " + displays[i].getName());
                addToLog("DISPLAY: " + displays[i].getDisplayId());
                try {
                    displays[i].getRealSize(point);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: REAL SIZE: " + point.toString());
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: X: " + point.x);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: Y: " + point.y);

                    displays[i].getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: DENSITY: " + displayMetrics.density);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: DENSITY_DPI: " + displayMetrics.densityDpi);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: HEIGHT PIXELS: " + displayMetrics.heightPixels);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: WIDTH PIXELS: " + displayMetrics.widthPixels);
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: METRICS: " + displayMetrics.toString());

                    addToLog("DISPLAY: ROTATION: " + displays[i].getRotation());
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: MODE: " + displays[i].getMode().toString());
                    //addToLog("DISPLAY: CUTOUT: " + displays[i].getCutout().toString());

                    Context displayContext = createDisplayContext(displays[i]);
                    Configuration displayConfiguration = displayContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
                    addToLog("DISPLAY: CONFIGURATION: " + displayConfiguration.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                }
            if (presentationDisplays.length > 0){
                SecondaryDisplay secondaryDisplay = new SecondaryDisplay(MainActivity.this, presentationDisplays[0]);
                secondaryDisplay.show();
            }
        }
```

With this particular display, if I rotate it back to Landscape and tell the display it's in Landscape mode - the phone screen shows up centered on the display

So the display may be doing something funky with it's rotation since it's still telling me it's in landscape vs. portrait.  I don't think TVs can communicate this so this Samsung display probably has some proprietary way of doing this.

Here's the output of my logging:

```
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: HDMI Screen
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: 118
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: REAL SIZE: Point(1920, 1080)
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: X: 1920
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: Y: 1080
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: DENSITY: 1.3312501
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: DENSITY_DPI: 213
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: HEIGHT PIXELS: 1080
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: WIDTH PIXELS: 1920
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: METRICS: DisplayMetrics{density=1.3312501, width=1920, height=1080, scaledDensity=1.3312501, xdpi=92.015, ydpi=91.44}
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: ROTATION: 0
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: MODE: {id=3286, width=1920, height=1080, fps=60.000004}
PRESENTATION_TEST: DISPLAY: CONFIGURATION: {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw811dp w1442dp h811dp 213dpi xlrg long land night -touch -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 75 - 1080, 2265) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.3849 desktop/d dc/d ?dcui ?dcaf bts=0 ff=0 bf=0 themeSeq=0}
```

So the TV/Display is causing my stretching / skewing - maybe I shouldnt use that and should build a portrait UI for a landscape display...

Based on this - how would you go about making a layout file that is rotated when the device doesn't believe it's rotated?

I'm not aware of any way to rotate all of the UI elements programatically.

Comment: "We have a few different types of external displays that we'll be using... I created an alternate layout folder called layout-port-television" -- AFAIK the `television` resource set qualifier is for code that is running on a television (e.g., Android TV), not for external displays. "(the TV is in portrait mode)" -- the Android device may not know this or may not be taking it into account correctly. Try logging the output from `getRealSize()` on your `Display`. Does it seem to match the characteristics of your external display, including the portrait orientation?

Comment: You might also consider running some tests with more conventional external displays (monitors, projectors, TVs in landscape mode) and see what results you get.

Comment: When I add the screen I get:

HDMI Screen
1920 x 1080
Density 1:3312501
Density DPI = 213
xdpi = 92.015
ydpi = 91.44

so I'm guessing that means it will use HDPI - right?

Sorry - very new to UI - mostly worked on other parts of apps and am just learning about this UI stuff now

I did find this - which seems helpful
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: "HDMI Screen 1920 x 1080" -- if that is literally what it spit out (1920 wide, 1080 high), then Android thinks that your external display is landscape. It is possible that your external display is then taking the 1080p landscape signal from Android and stretching/smashing it to fit 1080p portrait. So, I'm doubling down on the "test on something more normal" as your next step. If things look normal on something more normal, then your problem is not with your app, but with your portrait external display and Android's support for it.

Comment: In terms of what density bucket winds up being used for this display, rather than guessing, you can use [`createDisplayContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#createdisplaycontext) to get a `Context` for the `Display` that you are using. Then, call `getResources().getConfiguration()` on that `Context` to get a `Configuration`, and it will tell you exactly what density bucket will be used.

Comment: Interesting - what am I looking for here?  I see something strange in my debugging when I do this

The actual device screen is 1080x2400.

The TV shows up as 1920x1080 - so the TV is telling the phone it's in landscape but the content is presenting properly in portrait...

Comment: And then in the configuration for the external TV I see this when I do a .toString:  {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw811dp w1442dp h811dp 213dpi xlrg long land night -touch -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 75 - 1080, 2265) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.2838 desktop/d ?dc ?dcui ?dcaf bts=0 ff=0 bf=0 themeSeq=0}

Comment: That feels like you got the wrong `Configuration` and are getting the one tied to the device screen. If you used `createDisplayContext()`, I am not completely certain why you would get those results, but it has been a while since I fussed with this, so my memory may be foggy.